# Need to know timestamp of when Discord bot was last functioning

Tags: python, discord, bots

I am making a discord bot and I want for it to be able to take actions based on it being online.

However, I am running into the issue that I can't seem to figure out an easy way to know when the discord bot last went offline (which I need to know).

Currently I was trying to look into a way by using the activity of the bot in order to figure out when the bot goes offline since activities theoretically have timestamps from in the documentation. I don't know if this method would work this way but certainly I can't get it working and have the following trackback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\carol\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
     await coro(*args, **kwargs)   
File "C:\Users\carol\Code\Personal\visabot\visa_bot.py", line 128, in on_ready
     success =await self.add_visa_after_offline()   
File "C:\Users\carol\Code\Personal\visabot\visa_bot.py", line 103, in add_visa_after_offline
     async for active in visabot.activity.timestamps: 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'timestamps'
```

Here is the code for the specific function that errors:

```
async def add_visa_after_offline(self) -> bool:         
   guild = await self.get_guild()         
   visabot = await self.get_visabot_member()         
   async for active in visabot.activity.timestamps:             
      print(active)
```

And here is my intents:

```
client = MyClient(GUILD_ID, SPAM_CHANNEL, MAIN_CHANNEL,BOT_ID, intents=discord.Intents.all()) 
client.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

After combing through the documentation I didn't see anything that looked like this did exactly. Please let me know if there is any specific functionality for this or if there is some easier alternative way to know when the bot last went offline.

IF AT ALL POSSIBLE, I want to avoid having any kind of database, even a super simple one. So simply combing through discord stuff to infer last went offline would be much superior to solutions that use a database.

I mostly thought it would be an intent problem so I tried to let it have all intents. It could also be a permissions token problem and there is some permission its lacking. Looking at them though I am not sure that there is.

Additionally, I know that the visabot object is definitely the bot since .name, .id, and other methods work properly. Also the activity on the robot is "Watching" which I know since I can see it watching in the discord app.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please change the title to ***How to programmatically get discord bot offline status***? This will help more people on SO to understand the problem specifically quickly. Thanks

Comment: I don't really need to know the offline/online status of the bot though. I just specifically want to know the timestamp of when the bot last was "online" (in terms of functionality rather than as a discord variable though which I will try and correct).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "in order to figure out when the bot goes offline since activities theoretically have timestamps from in the documentation" The error is telling you that there is no **activity**, therefore it is not possible to get timestamps from it. "Also the activity on the robot is "Watching" which I know since I can see it watching in the discord app." Well, the code clearly disagrees, **at the time that** the function runs.

Comment: Please read [ask] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, and try to check what happens in the code, step by step (for example, by displaying the value of `visabot.activity` in the code before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by getting lazy and instead storing a variable of "LAST_ACTION" since my bot performs actions periodically. This will be a pretty accurate time of when the bot was last functional.

Relevant features:

Used a Json file for storage. Don't know if it was very optimal but it worked.

```
def get_json_data(self) -> dict:
    with open(self.tracker_file, 'r') as openfile:
      data = json.load(openfile)
    return data

  def update_json(self, new_data: dict) -> bool:
    data = self.get_json_data()
    data.update(new_data)

    with open(self.tracker_file, "w") as outfile:
      json.dump(data, outfile)
```

For initializing the client object I added:

```
def __init__(self, data, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    ... 
    ...
    ...
    self.tracker_file = "var_tracker.json"
    if not os.path.exists(self.tracker_file):
      now = get_now()
      # this will make it not really function well if you need to use this the first time
      init_data = {'LAST_TIME_OF_ACTION': str(now), 'ASSIGNED': []}
      with open(self.tracker_file, 'w') as openfile:
        json.dump(init_data, openfile)
    data = self.get_json_data()
    self.timestamp_before_online = data['LAST_TIME_OF_ACTION']
```

Then I made a function to reference the "self.timestamp_before_online" and get the timestamp since I have to convert from datetime to string to put in the json then back to datetime to use while coding. It was a little annoying to figure out though:

```
def get_now():
  return datetime.datetime.now((datetime.timezone.utc))


def str_datetime_to_datetime_obj(str_datetime: str) -> datetime.datetime:
  datetime_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_datetime,
                                            "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f%z")
  return datetime_obj

def search_last_around(self) -> datetime.datetime:
    last_around = str_datetime_to_datetime_obj(self.timestamp_before_online)
    return last_around
```

Finally, I simply updated the json for the "LAST_TIME_OF_ACTION "as the last line in my task loop:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=300)
  async def purge_visas_background_task(self):
    print("Attempting Purge at {}".format(get_now()))
    success = await self.purge_all_overstayed_visa()
    if success:
      pass
    else:
      await self.send_to_spam('Purge has failed')
      await self.report_error()
    now = get_now()
    self.update_json({'LAST_TIME_OF_ACTION': str(now)})
```

Not super elegant or compact but it works for my purposes so I thought I'd share it in case it helped anyone else.